# Want to extract data from an html file using batch script. But I am getting an error as Object does not support this property or method

Tags: javascript, html, batch-file

Below is my html code I want to extract data from div tag for class="lh-gauge__percentage" I have written a below batch script for the same but I am getting an error as Object does not support this property or method. Can anyone help me with this. Thanks.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "htmlfile=google.html"

rem // invoke JScript hybrid code and capture its output
for /f %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%htmlfile%"') do set "converted=%%I"

echo %converted%

rem // end main runtime
goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    DOM = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'),
    htmlfile = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1),
    html = htmlfile.ReadAll();
 
DOM.write(html);
htmlfile.Close();

var scrape = DOM.getElementsByClassName('lh-gauge__percentage')[0].innerText;

WSH.Echo(scrape.match(/^.*=\s+(\S+).*$/)[0]);
```

```html
<a -------
    <div class="lh-gauge__percentage">63</div>
    <div class="lh-gauge__label">Performance</div>
  </a>
<a -------
    <div class="lh-gauge__percentage">58</div>
    <div class="lh-gauge__label">Progressive Web App</div>
  </a>
```

Comment: The batch is not providing this error, that is a jscript runtime error. My guess would be that the method you created as variable `scrape` is not supported.

Comment: Yes. It ia a javascript error. Can anything other than var scrape = DOM.getElementsByClassName('lh-gauge__percentage')[0].innerText; be used?